# pandas read_sql_table sqlalchemy chunksize issue

Tags: pandas

I am very new to python and I have an issue with the read_sql_table part of pandas.
If I simply provide the table name and the engine from sqlalchemy, it reads the data and I am able to print the head of the dataframe.
If I add index_col and columns, it works as well.
As soon as I add CHUNKSIZE as 10000, it fails to print the head with the error 'generator' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: Please also post a snippet of what all you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over it:

```py
for chunk in pd.read_sql_table(table_name, chunksize=10000):
    print(chunk.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

A generator in Python is a way to lazily evaluate things.
So there simply isn't anything to get the `.head()` of when you provide input to the `chunksize` keyword argument.

What you'll need to become familiar with is iterating over those results.
Example:

```
generator_object = pd.read_sql_table('your_table',con=your_connection_string,
                                     chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
for chunk in generator_object:
    print(chunk)
```

Another thing you can do is to request the first chunk of your table with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
generator_object = pd.read_sql_table('your_table',con=your_connection_string,
                                     chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
next(generator_object).head()
```

But *please note* that this *consumes* the chunk, and `generator_object` will no longer return that chunk.

Further reading:
You can also get multiple chunks using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools as it

CHUNKSIZE = 10
iterable_slice = it.islice(generator_object,3) # get 3*10 == 30 records

for chunk in iterable_slice:
    print(chunk)
```